# #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert ID field from one table to another using below query:

```
INSERT INTO `srikprag_db`.`acbalance`
SELECT `id` FROM `srikprag_mlm`.`member_table`
```

Error is showing:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: acbalance probably has more than one column but in the select statement it's only trying to add a value to one column

Comment: @user1490835 That's not correct. `srikprag_db` is the database, `acbalance` is the table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You did not define the destination column on where the values from the `SELECT` statement will be saved, eg.

```
INSERT INTO srikprag_db.acbalance (ID)            -- <<== destination column
SELECT id
FROM   srikprag_mlm.member_table
```

probably you want to manipulate records across database.

Comment: I also had to specify column names because both tables does not have same number of columns in them.
INSERT INTO `db_name`.`table_name`(col1, col2, col3) SELECT * FROM `db_name`.`table_name`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your query you are not assigning any value to the column. You have 1 column with zero value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id` FROM `srikprag_mlm`.`member_table`
```

returns a result set with only 1 column (`id`).

The `acbalance` table probably has more than 1 column.