# MySQL auto-increment primary key causing value count mismatch and foreign-key error

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chug_dedup_instances(
left_chug_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY fk_left_chug_name(left_chug_name) REFERENCES chugim(name)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
right_chug_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY fk_right_chug_name(right_chug_name) REFERENCES chugim(name)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
chug_dedup_instance_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I tried to insert into this table like this:

```
INSERT INTO chug_dedup_instances VALUES ("Swimming", "Swimming");
```

This returns an error:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

If I remove the chug_dedup_instance_id primary key, then the insert works fine. It also works if I give the ID value explicitly:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO chug_dedup_instances VALUES ("Swimming", "Swimming", 0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

This seems wrong to me: shouldn't the database supply the key value?  I don't think this is a dup of [PHP, MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931900/php-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1), because I'm asking why the auto-increment field is not being added automatically, as I believe it should be.

I tried removing the primary key and instead using a unique key on the two main values:

```
UNIQUE KEY uk_chug_dedup_instances(left_chug_name, right_chug_name))
```

I find that when I do this, I can't delete from the source table (chugim) that the two foreign keys reference- the database reports that the constraint is broken:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails    (`camprama_chugbot_db`.`chug_dedup_instances`, CONSTRAINT `chug_dedup_instances_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`right_chug_name`) REFERENCES `chugim` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I would have expected the child table fields to be updated, since the table has "ON UPDATE CASCADE".

I've copied the source table ("chugim") definition below.  Any help with either of these questions would be appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chugim(
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
group_id int,
FOREIGN KEY fk_group(group_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
max_size int NULL,
min_size int NULL DEFAULT 0,
description varchar(2048),
UNIQUE KEY uk_chugim(name, group_id),
chug_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: "Column count doesn't match value count" is quite simple. You need to provide a value for each column. If it's an autoincrement column, you can use `NULL` as a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293681/1136-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931900/php-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: I was asking why the auto-increment column was not automatically updated.  You don't need to provide a value or use NULL, but it turns out you do need to list each column name.  This works: INSERT INTO chug_dedup_instances (left_chug_name, right_chug_name) VALUES ("Swimming", "Swimming");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear: I was asking why an auto-increment column was not automatically updated when I inserted the other values. It turns out that you need to list each non-auto-incremented column name. This works:

```
INSERT INTO chug_dedup_instances (left_chug_name, right_chug_name) VALUES ("Swimming", "Swimming"); 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

> If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement. If you do not know the order of the columns in the table, use DESCRIBE tbl_name to find out.

If you don't use columns list in INSERT statement, you **must** set values for **all** columns in table explicitly in the right order. There is no exception for auto-increment column.