# What MySQL commands can use column order instead of names

Tags: mysql

I have and old MySQL database where I need to insert new columns into tables (to support new parts of the front-end). But some of the old parts use SQL commands that depend on column count and order instead of their names. e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES (null /*auto-id*/, "name", "description", ...)
```

When I add new columns into this table, I get [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16293681/2011448):

> ## 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Right now I know about the INSERT which needs to be changed to:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`name`, `desc`, ...) VALUES ("name", "description", ...)
```

**The question is: are there any other commands that can use similar syntax that rely on an order or count of the columns instead of their names?** I need to update all the old SQL commands before updating the DB and using [trial & error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error) method would be really long.

*SELECTs are not a problem, because the front-end uses associative mapping and correctly uses their names everywhere so new columns will be just ignored. Also I'm sure there are no commands that modifying the DB structure (e.g. ALTER TABLE).*

Comment: Not answering your question, but additional columns may unintentionally influence queries using NATURAL JOIN.

Comment: Or queries using unions.

Comment: Or existing SELECT statements that use unqualified column references,  column addition can cause new "ambiguous column" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ruled out data structure modifying queries, so this leaves us with insert, update, delete, and select.

Insert you are already aware of.

Update requires each updated field to be specified, so mostly that's ok. However, subqueries may be used in the where clause, and mysql allows multi-table updates, so my points around select do apply.

Delete applies to a whole record, so there is nothing that an extra field would influence. However, subqueries may be used in the where clause, so my points around select do apply.

You tried to rule out select, but you should not. It is not only the final resultset that can be influenced by a new field:

1. A subquery may use `select *` that and an extra field may cause error in the outer query. For example the newly introduced field mayhave the same name as another field in the outer query leading to ambiguous field name error.
2. If `select *` is used in union, then column counts may not match after adding a new field.
3. Natural joins may also be affected by an introduction of a new field.